# ASP.NET Core blank application startup.cs

Tags: c#, .net-core, routes

I am trying to follow along with a pluralsight course creating in VStudio 2019 a blank
ASP .NET core project with an empty project template.

My startup.cs differs significantly from the course in that it does not have

`app.UseRouting()` and `app.useEndpoints()`

my startup.cs basically has only `app.Run()`

I recreated project 2 times to make sure I followed directions, I made sure my .Net Core and CLR were the most recent versions. Google search revealed no useful information. I assume
I am missing something fundamental. I made sure I created like course did use blank solution and empty project template.

My newly created solution runs fine so I presume there is some "version problem" or something changed in terms of the way things are done?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have done something wrong as if you look at the [doco](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

> All ASP.NET Core templates include routing in the generated code. Routing is registered in the middleware pipeline in Startup.Configure.
>
> ```
> public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
> {
>     if (env.IsDevelopment())
>     {
>         app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
>     }
>
>     app.UseRouting();
>
>     app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
>     {
>         endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
>         {
>             await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
>         });
>     });
> }
> ```

This is with Core 3.1 - check the verson of Core app you are creating.

Comment: @SMM Glad I could help, feel free to accept this response as the correct answer. Questions with no accepted answer continue to appear in the Unanswered list.